# forEach() function on NodeList elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function to convert string to react component and an **element** variable with nodelist and I need to use forEach loop to create for example two components from one **element**.

In this moment I'm getting an error:

```
TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
```

And I don't know how to resolve them :(

My function:

```
    const htmlStrToReactComponent = (str) => {
        const dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html')

        const element = dom.documentElement.firstChild.childNodes // in this line I have for example 2x [object HTMLScriptElement]

        element.forEach(function (currentValue){ // loop to extract the two elements
            const NodeName = currentValue.nodeName.toLowerCase()

            const scriptAttributes = Object.fromEntries([...element.attributes]
                .map(({ nodeName, nodeValue }) => [nodeName, nodeValue]))

            return <NodeName {...scriptAttributes} />
        })
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `.map()` instead of `.forEach()`?  Those `return`s aren't going to do anything from within a `.forEach()`.

Comment: In which browser are you running the code? In which line is that error thrown?

Comment: I'm running the code in Chrome. Error is in line with `const scriptAttributes = Object.fromEntries([...element.attributes]`

Answer (score 1):

Fix `[...element.attributes]` into `[...currentValue.attributes]`.

Solution 2: If you want to convert HTML string to React element, you can try [react-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser)